# python3-picamera package not found

Tags: camera, picamera

running rpi4B. I performed update and upgrade. Then I attempted:
sudo apt install python3-picamera2.
result: cannot find package python3-picamera2.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've given, you may have encountered a problem due to a few potential reasons:

1. **Package Name**: The package name might be incorrect. The package you're referring to is generally known as `python3-picamera`, not `python3-picamera2`. If `python3-picamera2` is a newer version or a different package, you might need to add a new repository to your sources list that contains it.
2. **Raspberry Pi OS version**: Different versions of Raspberry Pi OS have different packages available in their repositories. It could be the case that the package is not available for your version of the OS.

Here are some steps you can try to troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Check the Package Name**: Try installing with the correct package name. Run this command in the terminal:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-picamera
```

2. **Update and Upgrade**: Make sure your package list is up to date. This can be done by running:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then, try to install the package again.

3. **Python Pip**: If the package is still not found, you can try installing it via pip, the Python package manager. First, ensure that pip is installed:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then install the picamera module:

```bash
pip3 install picamera
```

Remember that you might need to use `sudo pip3 install picamera` if you run into permission issues.

4. **Check Raspberry Pi OS Version**: If you're still encountering issues, double-check your OS version and consider updating or upgrading to a version that supports the `python3-picamera` package.

Note: Raspberry Pi 4B typically runs 64-bit OS, and sometimes certain packages are not available for the 64-bit version but are for the 32-bit version. Make sure the package is available for your architecture.

I hope this helps! If you're still encountering issues, please provide further details and I'll be happy to assist further.

Comment: Do not advise people to use `apt-get` - they may miss vital prompts. *apt provides a high-level commandline interface for the package management system. It is intended as an end user interface and enables some
       options better suited for interactive usage by default compared to more specialized APT tools like apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8).*

Comment: Is this answer AI generated?

Comment: 1. Picamera2 is the correct package name. It is apparently required for camera 3 units.

Answer (score 1):

This package is available in Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye (at least if up to date):-

```
python3-picamera2/stable,stable 0.3.12-1 all
  Libcamera based python library
```

Comment: Looks promising. How do I access it?

Comment: What "it" are you referring to? You have not provided any details in your original question about OS.

Comment: Sorry. I meant the python3-picamera package. Further, I find that I am using the buster OS. Maybe that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: It is only available on Bullseye https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/picamera2-beta-release/